# When click button value not update in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

This html code :

```
<md-button class="md-primary " ng-click="setDevice('phone')">Phone           
        </md-button>
<md-button class="md-primary " ng-click="setDevice('tablet')">
           Tablet
        </md-button>

<div class="area-{{setDevice}}">
    <me-iphone tmp-url="{{appTemplateUrl}}"></me-iphone>
</div>
```

First Time When Click Phone or Tablet Button Update setDevice Value

```
$scope.setDevice = "";
$scope.setDevice = function(setDevice){
            $scope.setDevice = setDevice;
        }
```

The problem is (First Click phone), When Click Tablet Button Not update setDevice Value

When click both button, hope to update `$scope.setDevice` Value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although, your line of thinking is correct, you've messed it up a little bit in syntax. :)
Which is okay and an essential step in learning.

In your code, you have declared your `setDevice`, first, as a string and then as a function. Becuase the last assignment is a function, your `$scope.setDevice` is no longer a string, but a function.

Change the name of the variable to something else and it will work fine.

```
$scope.currentDevice = "";
$scope.setDevice = function(setDevice){
    $scope.currentDevice = setDevice;
}
```

And in your `HTML`

```
<md-button class="md-primary " ng-click="setDevice('phone')">Phone</md-button>
<md-button class="md-primary " ng-click="setDevice('tablet')">Tablet</md-button>

<div class="area-{{currentDevice}}"> <!-- THIS NEEDS TO BE UPDATED AS WELL -->
    <me-iphone tmp-url="{{appTemplateUrl}}"></me-iphone>
</div>
```

Comment: New post when I was about to answer pretty much the same. +1

Comment: Update "currentDevice" Value But not refresh div tag. What can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean `But not refresh div tag`? Angular has 2 way data binding. You don't need to update/refresh tags (DOM) :)

Comment: Your are correct. I double checked my code, There was syntax error. I fixed that. It's now working. Thanks you for reminded me this idea about angular js.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code just like this:

```
$scope.setDevice = function(setDevice){
   return setDevice;
}
```